# mysqli_multi_query with CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysqli, create-table, insert-into, mysqli-multi-query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
$send_to_mysql = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

OK.

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE abc (a varchar(255), b varchar(255), c varchar(255))";
$send_to_mysql = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

OK.

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE abc (a varchar(255), b varchar(255), c varchar(255))";
$query .= "INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
$send_to_mysql = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
```

nop. Where's the problem?

Comment: A missing semicolon separator ?

Comment: Haha. Can't belive. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a semicolon between your two queries. As you are putting your two queries into one single string, you need to separate them in order for MySQL to understand that you do have two queries :

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE abc (a varchar(255), b varchar(255), c varchar(255));";
$query .= "INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put semicolon as separator between two queries like

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE abc (a varchar(255), b varchar(255), c varchar(255));";
mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
$query = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
$send_to_mysql = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query);
```